# Can't I install Django on the web host which supports python?

Tags: django

The title says it all.There are web hosts which say they support python but are silent about Django.So will they support Django,if I install Django on their servers manually.

Comment: I guess so. Do you have any specific hosting provider in mind?

Comment: Often yes, but it's not always that straightforward. You might want to just come right out and ask them or google to see if anyone else has tried that particular combination. You should research your prospective web hosts for things like reliability and listen to friends' recommendations and so forth anyway. Oh and yes you can get hosts which support python but will not run django.

Comment: Yes,I am talking about bigrock.in.They advertise python support on their main page but they said that they don't support Django when I asked them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things to consider when determining if a shared host is a viable option to run Django.

1. Shell access (ssh)
2. Python support (2.6+)
3. Allows long running processes
4. Preferrably supports WSGI applications OR supports fastcgi

Some shared hosts will not allow you to run any long running processes, which means you would only be able to run django via CGI and that would really be poor quality.

Python support alone may not always be enough. They may only give you the ability to run scripts, but not necessarily daemon processes or applications that continue to run.

For a reference example, you can look at how dreamhost documents support for running Django: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django
They actually support WSGI or FCGI. Other hosts might only give you a FCGI option.

Here is another example, from hostgator, where they explain how to set up django via fastcgi: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi

Answer (score 2):

You'll need command-line access to do anything real with Django, which pretty much means SSH access, which *most* shared hosting provider will not give you. Support for Python may only be support for deploying a pre-configure application that they have approved. If you can get SSH access, then you'll be fine. Otherwise, keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.3 supports python >= 2.4

Django 1.4 supports python >= 2.5

If your hosting provider supports those you should be able to install Django, you may need to jump through a few hoops in order to install Django and other related python libraries that you install as well as to have them in your sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use shared hosting - two options: 
 1. They support Django as one click install, then there is no problem for installing it. Just a couple of clicks, then you can change/add/delete django files...
 2. They have Python (most of the hostings do), assure the version of the Python is no bigger than 2.7
If you want to use VPS or dedicated hosting. I don't thing you'll have any problems to install Django and any Python version.
Hope this helps...